# image_dataset_from_directory using a subset of sub-directories

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn

I have downloaded the MINC dataset for material classification which consists of 23 cateogories. However, I am only interested in a subset of the categories (e.g. [wood, foliage, glass, hair])

Is it possible to get a subset of the data using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`?

I have tried `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(folder_dir, label_mode="categorical", class_names=["wood", "foliage", "glass", "hair"])` but it give this error `` The `class_names` passed did not match the names of the subdirectories of the target directory. ``

Is there a way to get a subset of the directories without deleting or modifying the folders? I know `datagen.flow_from_directory` is able to do it but keras says that it is deprecated and I should use `image_dataset_from_directory`.

Answer (score 0):

`class_name`  excepect labels to match subclasses dir
Example: if you have labels `['cat', 'dog']` you have to have a cat & dog subdirectory in your training dir    `train_dir/cat`   & `train_dir/dog`

I think you can solve your problem by only including the classes of interest in your training dir